# Ajuda com Asset (Blade do Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

tudo bem?

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com o framework Laravel.
No meu projeto consigo chamar um arquivo js, porém o mesmo não funciona.

```
  <script src="{{asset('js/formCurriculo.js')}}" type="text/javascript" async="true" defer></script>
```

Ao reparar no console me deparo com este erro:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZwho.png]

Antes de "public" está vindo com 2 barras acho que o problema é este, porém não sei resolver. Por isso estou aqui e peço ajuda pra vocês.

Comment: Seu arquivo está salvo com a extensão .blade.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

se você não preceder o caminho com uma barra invertida

Se você começar com um nome, seu navegador assumirá que o que você quer está no diretório atual.

Você tem que pensar na velha escola, onde tudo foi baseado em pastas.

Então, se sua url é `myhost.com/postse` você pede `js/scriptname.js`, seu navegador pede `myhost.com/js/scriptname.js` porque está pensando que você quer dizer que js está na mesma pasta que as postagens.

O problema, então, vem quando você está na "pasta" `myhosts.com/posts/my-favourite-post` porque seu navegador tentará carregar, `myhost.com/posts/js/scriptname.js` pois pensa que js está na pasta atual.

por outro lado

Se você iniciar o seu caminho do recurso com uma barra, ou seja, `/js/scriptname.js`, o navegador assume que a pasta js está fora da pasta raiz - não importa quantas pastas você esteja no URL

**simplificando. é só começar com barra seu código de import**

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/formCurriculo.js') }}" type="text/javascript" async="true" defer></script>
```

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado deu certo, porém, não entendi o que aconteceu.

Answer (score 1):

Lembrando que isso pode depender da configuração do seu Webpack e caminho do Htdocs. Mas creio que assim deve funcionar :

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/formCurriculo.js') }}" type="text/javascript" async="true" defer></script>
```

Dá uma olhada depois nas melhores práticas. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#vanilla-js

Answer (score 1):

O arqivo está salvo com a extensão `.blade.php`?

Por que da pergunta?
O resultado impresso deveria ser algo como:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="nttp://localhost8000/js/algo.js"></script>
```

No caso de um servidor web, deveria aparecer o domínio depois a pasta `js` e não a `public`.